# Search for a String, and retrieve the line having it and all lines following it until another specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Using linux, I want to search a text file for the string `Blah` and then return the line full line that contained the string and all the lines following the pattern up until a line that contains the word `Failed`.

For example,

```
Test Case Name "Blah"
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
Failed
Test Case Name "Foo"
Pass
Test Case Name "Red"
Pass
```

In the above, I want to search for "Blah", and then return:

```
Test Case Name "Blah"
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
```

Up until the line `Failed`. There can be any number of "Error" lines between `Blah` and `Failed`.

**Follow up to make it faster**

Both sed and awk options worked.

```
sed '/Blah/!d;:a;n;/Failed/d;ba' file
```

and

```
awk '/Failed/{p=0}/Blah/{p=1}p;' file
```

However, I noticed that while returning the expected outcome is quite fast, it takes ages to exit. Maybe these commands are recurrently searching for `Blah` and given that it appears only once, they run until the end-of-file.
This would not be much of a problem but I'm working with a file that contains 10 million lines and for now it is painfully slowly.

Any suggestions on how to exit after finding both lines containing `Blah` and `Failed` would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: With GNU sed: `sed -n '/Blah/,/Failed/{/Failed/d;p}' file`

Comment: Thanks Cyrus! This produced almost the correct output. Test Case Name "Blah"
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3. However, also include the line containing "Failed", which should be left out. Any suggestion to make it right?

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed '/Blah/,/Failed/!d;//{1!d;}' file
```

- `/Blah/`: match lines from `Blah`to `Failed`
- `!d`: do not delete previous matching lines
- `//{1!d;}`: from lines matching the addresses (that is `Blah`and `Failed`), do not delete the first one `1!d`.

Comment: Thanks  SLePort. This resulted in:
 
Error 1
Error 2
Error 3
 
But missed the line containing "Blah"

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Blah/,/Failed/{/Failed/!p}' file
```

Print the lines between and including `Blah` to `Failed` unless the line contains `Failed`.

```
    sed ':a;/Blah/!d;:b;n;/Failed/ba;bb' file
```

If a line does not contain `Blah` delete it. Otherwise, print the current line and fetch the next (`n`). If this line contains `Failed` delete it and begin next iteration. Otherwise, repeat until successful or end-of-file.

The first solution prevents `Blah` and `Failed` being printed if they inhabit the same line. The second alternative, allows this.

Comment: Thanks potong!!!!  The second option produced the right output! If possible, could you kindly expand your explanation to include what each element is doing?

Comment: Thanks, that makes it much clearer. Just wondering if the "begin next iteration" means that once "Failed" is found, sed will be looking for "Blah" again and repeating the process until the end of file.

Comment: @RaulMiranda sed [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Execution-Cycle)

Answer (score 1):

would you like do with awk?
`awk '/Failed/{p=0}/Blah/{p=1}p;' file` will works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked your suggestion again and I noticed that I made a mistake the first time. It actually works too. Do you know if awk is faster than sed?